# ROS2- passing arguments with launch.py file not working

Tags: ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Folks,

I am trying to launch nodes with `launch.py` in ros2. Nodes are getting launched but I am facing issue with arguments passing.

My Code snippet:

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='tf2_ros', node_executable='static_transform_publisher',node_name='bl_imu', output='screen',
            #arguments=['-0.07' '0' '0' '3.14159' '0' '0' 'base_link' 'laser' '100']),         
            #arguments=['--x','-0.07', '--y', '0', '--z', '0', '--qx', '3.14159', '--qy', '0', '--qz' ,'0', '--qw','1.570796327','--      #frame_id','base_link','--child_frame_id','imu_link']),
```

I would like to pass arguments to this node `static_transform_publisher`.

I tried above two ways but getting error with this specific node.

```
[ERROR] []: static_transform_publisher exited due to not having the right number of arguments
A command line utility for manually sending a transform.
Usage: static_transform_publisher x y z qx qy qz qw frame_id child_frame_id 
OR 
Usage: static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id 
[ERROR] [launch]: process[static_transform_publisher-1] process has died [pid 7074, exit code 255, cmd '/opt/ros/bouncy/lib/tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher __node:=bl_imu'].
```

Please let me know if anybody has tried this or any suggestions.

Thanks,
Poonam

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309413/ros2--passing-arguments-with-launch.py-file-not-working/) by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2018-11-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-27**:
I am also running into this issue. I tried passing the arguments as a single string (`arguments='0 0 0 0 0 0 1 world cam'`), but extra spaces were inserted (`cmd '/opt/ros/bouncy/lib/tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   w o r l d   c a m'`).

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-11-29**:
Hi,

I am able to pass this via command line as below and it works.

ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 -0.3 0.52 -1.570796327 0 1.570796327 base_link imu_link

but i would like to do the same from launc.py file

Thanks,
poonam

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-29**:
Yes, I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. The correct way to pass argument is as a list of strings, as in your first attempt.  The issue is simply the last argument `'100'`. Try creating the node as follows.

```
transform = launch_ros.actions.Node(package='tf2_ros', node_executable='static_transform_publisher',
    arguments=['-0.07', '0', '0', '3.14159', '0', '0', 'base_link', 'laser'])
```

---

Originally posted by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) with karma: 121 on 2018-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-11-30**:
thanks a lot ..its really working and not throwing error for arguments.
By any chance, have you tried to pass arguments like this .

```
launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument( 'output_final_position', default_value='false'),
```

here , when declaring more that one argument, it throws error.

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-12-05**:
I haven't used this function, but have you tried declaring each argument in a separate call? E.g., `DeclareLaunchArgument('arg1', default_value='x', 'arg2', default_value='2')` would become `DeclareLaunchArgument('arg1', default_value='x')` and `DeclareLaunchArgument('arg2', default_value='2')`.

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-12-05**:
Also, if this answer worked for you, please mark it as correct.

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-12-06**:
@beck,
thanks , it is working.